# CXF WebService & HTTPS

Tags: java, web-services, cxf

I'm working on a Web Service that will be published on a Web Logic server and in front of it, there will be an Apache server that will attend all the requests and direct them to the proper WL instance but using HTTPS.
The problem here is that I'm letting CXF generate the WSDL directly, so if you access

https://myapp.com/myapp/ws/

It will show you all the published services and their corresponding WSDL. The problem is that this doesn't appear to be considering the https prefix, and instead, it shows the URL corresponding to the http one, which is not allowed and not responding. 
If you copy and paste any of those URLs and add an 's' to the HTTP in the URL, the content appears just fine, but the same problem happens inside the WSDL with the "location URL" in the import:

```
<wsdl:import location="http://myapp.com:80/myapp/ws/AdminService?wsdl=AdminService.wsdl" namespace="http://myapp.com/"></wsdl:import>
```

So, any application or user that tries to use that WSDL gets an error because the client is unable to obtain the import file.

My question is, is there any way to specify this? Am I doing something wrong?

Here's the interface:

```
@WebService
@SOAPBinding(style = SOAPBinding.Style.DOCUMENT, use = SOAPBinding.Use.LITERAL, parameterStyle = ParameterStyle.WRAPPED)
public interface AdminService {

@WebResult(name = "message")
public String createUser(
        @WebParam(name = "adminUser") AdminUser adminUser,
        @WebParam(name = "queryUser") QueryUser queryUser)
        throws AdminServiceException;
}
```

And the actual class:

```
public class AdminServiceImpl implements AdminService,
        InitializingBean {
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is the server? Weblogic?

Comment: Yes, Oracle Weblogic 11.

Comment: Can you show some of the code of your web service's java class? The declaration, the `public class` part of it and some stuff around.

Comment: I'll update the answer in a few.